# How to avoid bracket for theorem environment (authoryear) argument?

Tags: citing, theorems, amsthm

Is there a way to avoid brackets for the argument of a theorem environment?

I want to see `Theorem 1 [1].` instead of `Theorem 1 ([1]).`.

Here is an mwe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{general.bib}
@misc{somebody,
  author = {Somebody},
  year = {2000},
  title = {A generic title},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{general.bib}


\begin{document}
%
\begin{theorem}[Somebody]
This is an amazing theorem.
\end{theorem}
%
\begin{theorem}[\cite{somebody}]
This is an amazing theorem.
\end{theorem}
%
\begin{theorem}\cite{somebody}
This is an amazing theorem.
\end{theorem}

\noindent The following look is what I am trying for.\\

\noindent \textbf{Theorem 4 \cite{somebody}.}
This is an amazing theorem.
%
\printbibliography
%
\end{document}
```

The code gives the following output.

[image]

One solution is to print the citation without bracket. So, it will look like `Theorem 1 (1).`; this is not consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a special theorem environment for the task.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{somebody,
  author = {Somebody},
  year = {2000},
  title = {A generic title},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newtheoremstyle{noparentheses}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} \thmnote{#3}}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{noparentheses}
\newtheorem{theorem*}[theorem]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Somebody]
This is an amazing theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}[\cite{somebody}]
This is an amazing theorem.
\end{theorem*}

\noindent The following look is what I am trying for.

\vspace{\topsep}

\noindent \textbf{Theorem 3 \cite{somebody}.}
\textit{This is an amazing theorem.}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The new theorem style is the same as the default `plain`, but it omits the parentheses around the attribution (you're better having one when using `theorem*`).

[image]

Comment: Okay. So, the edited part is CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC. Thanks for your answer.